# I can not access my local xampp (apache) server using my real IP, only by localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: apache, xampp

So here is the trouble. I recently moved to live in an apartment, where now I have a new internet. In my old place, I could access my server using my own IP address, localhost, or 127.0.0.1. I had this issue there at home as-well, but I managed to solve it that time, don't remember how.

So the issue is. I **can not** access my localhost using **my real IP**, but can using localhost.

Comment: maybe you need to modify the apache/httpd conf file of your xampp install by changing the "ServerName" line, replacing "localhost" by your ip.

Comment: Let me try quick ^^

Comment: Sorry, does not do the trick.. :/

Comment: I think this is something to do with a missing config to the router.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Apache config file **httpd.conf** (line 228) replace :

> ServerName **localhost**:80

with :

> ServerName **Your_Real_IP**:80